# Methods in a class. Should you set properties and have the method use properties or pass arguments?

Tags: class, oop

Lets say i have a class to calculate tax. Which is the best practice to design the calcTax method. Option 1 or Option 2. The object pertains to a person and that is why we are storing age and income. I can see the pros and cons of each but just wanted to see if there is a best practice or if one of the two options has a code smell.

Option 1:

```
    class CalcTax
    {
        private int Age;
        private double Income;

        public void Update(int age, double inc)
        {
            Age = age;
            Income = inc;
        }

        public double calcTax()
        {
            return Age * Income * 0.25;
        }

    }

    CalcTax obj = new CalcTax();
    obj.update(5,500)
    obj.CalcTax();
```

Option 2:

```
    class CalcTax
    {

        public double calcTax(int age, int inc)
        {
            return age * inc* 0.25;
        }
    }

    CalcTax obj = new CalcTax();
    obj.calcTax(10,100);
```

Comment: It depends. The design is yours. What is the object supposed to represent? A tax calculator? Why does the second option have any fields?

Answer (score 0):

Could go either way.  Depends on what the object is supposed to represent.

If it there is one object for one person (I'm assuming Age and Income relate to a person), and that object is going to be doing a variety of things beyond the one calculation you show, then the fundamental attributes of that person (Age, Income, etc.) should be class attributes.  These would likely be set as parameters to `new()` or perhaps set shortly after the instance was created.

If, however, this is just a calculator object, to be used to process requests for a variety of people, then there is no need to have Age and Income as class attributes at all.  You could delete them your Option 2 example entirely, and just have them in the parameters to calcTax().

It probably ends there, with one of those options best matching your project. But if you're creating more of a library function that other programmers will be using in different ways in different projects, you could straddle the fence a bit...

Take Age and Income as parameters to new() and save them as class attributes.  Then, make the parameters to calcTax() optional, and default to the class attributes if none are provided.  That way, your developers can take whichever approach suits their needs best, and you've got a single codebase to support them both.

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment says, the choice is yours.  Try to think about what role your class will play.  Is it just a collection of common math functions that you may want to call.  If so, then methods with passable parameters are great.

However, if you're generating a tax class that will be specific to a certain context, then maybe something like the below would be best for you.  The example below requires the Age and Income and offers up the CalculatedTax as a read-only property.

```
public class Tax
    {
        public Tax(int Age, int Income) //constructor, class can not be instantiated without these values
        {
            this.Age = Age;
            this.Income = Income;
        }

        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Income { get; set; }
        public double CalculatedTax //read only property
        {
            get { return double.Parse((Age * Income).ToString()) * 0.25f; } 
        }
    }

Tax tax = new Tax(5, 1000);
double calculatedTax = tax.CalculatedTax; //1250
```

One benefit to the above example is that Age and Income are required to generate the CalculatedTax value.  By forcing these parameters to be entered in the constructor you  make sure they exist, otherwise (for this example) if these were your only three  properties, what would be the point of making a class if you weren't going to include one of the required parameters.